# Declaring an array of type String containing numbers with padding

Tags: c++, string, loops

I am trying to create an array of `String` that contain numbers. These numbers are the names of folders that I need to access. Currently I am declaring it as shown below:

```
String str1[] = { "001", "002", "003", "004", "005", "006", "007", "008", "009", "010", "011", "012", "013", "014", "015", "016", "017", "018", "019", "020", };
```

I have 124 folders and naming them in such fashion is tedious. Is there a better way to do this? I am working with C++.

Comment: Use a for-loop and initialize your array dynamically

Comment: I don't know what to call it Padding or Precision but for-loop will give me 1,2,3... not 001,002,003 etc...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use a stringstream and for loop.

Example:

```
uint32_t t150()
{
   std::vector<std::string> strVec; // i.e. String str1[]
   for (int i=1; i<125; ++i)
   {
      std::stringstream ss;
      ss << std::setw(3) << std::setfill('0') << i;
      strVec.push_back(ss.str());
   }

   for (int i=0; i<124; ++i)
      std::cout << strVec[i] << std::endl;

   return(0);
}
```

---

An alternative is something like:

```
std::string t150b(int i) {
    std::stringstream ss;
    ss << std::setw(3) << std::setfill('0') << i;
    return (ss.str());
}
// not tested, and no range check
```

which returns the formatted string for the value i ... I imagine you have the loop at some higher level code.

---

Another alternative is to skip the vector, just build the string with white spaces between ... then fetch them like you fetch any file item ...

```
void t150c(std::stringstream& ss)
{
   for (int i=1; i<125; ++i) {
      ss << std::setw(3) << std::setfill('0') << i << "  ";
      // white space between values -------------------^^
   }
}
```

Usage example:

```
{
   std::stringstream ss;
   t150c(ss);  // 'fill' stream with desired strings

   do {
      if(ss.eof()) break;
      std::string s;
      ss >> s;       // extract string one at a time
      std::cout << s << std::endl;  // and use
   }while(1);
}
```

Comment: What does your function return?

Comment: I have inserted some code -- the return would be what I've called strVec.

Comment: @AtlasC1 - I think of it as test 150, just a name to distinguish this function from the others.  It is not designed for a specific application, but rather to demonstrate the ideas I recommended (use of vector and stringstream).

Answer (score 5):

You can use stringstreams and set the format options to fill the integer to a certain number of characters and set the filling character.

Edit: Ok my code doesn't begin with 1 but 0, but I'm sure you can figure that out :)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    std::vector<std::string> strs;
    for (int i = 0; i < 124; i++)
    {
        std::ostringstream os;
        os << std::setfill('0') << std::setw(3) << i;
        strs.push_back(os.str());
    }

    for (const auto& s : strs)
    {
        std::cout << s << "\n";
    }
}
```

Live example: http://ideone.com/TEV2iq

Answer (score 0):

```
std::string str1[124];
for(int i = 1; i <= 124; i++){
    str1[i-1] = convertTo3Digit(i);
}
```

Then just write the `convertTo3Digit` function to take the numerical value and format it into a 3-digit string.

Another less elegant way would be to format a column in excel to be three-digit numbers and generate 001-124 and then copy-paste into your static initializer.  You can use regex to add the quotes and commas.